# Example of taxonomies in interface design and its benefits and drawbacks?

Tags: taxonomy

What is an example(s) of taxonomies in interface design? What are the benefits? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: Thats a very generic question,can you elaborate a little ?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me.

Comment: Hi Tala, welcome to UX! Please add more information about what kind of taxonomies you're looking for? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taxonomy is basically 'organizing and categorizing information'.

In terms of interface design, you need to know what the interface is interacting with. The advantage of the taxonomy is you have a structure to design for.